# Iterate through files using Twig

Tags: php, twig

I have a for loop written in PHP that for each .html file in the folder 'patterns', it grabs the html information and renders it, and also places the html contents on the page for reference. The php code was taken from the Styleguide Generator found here:

https://github.com/adactio/Pattern-Primer/blob/master/index.php

How would I take the code below and convert it to something Twig templating engine can use?

```
<?php
$files = array();
$handle=opendir('patterns');
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))):
    if(substr($file, -5) == '.html'):
        $files[] = $file;
    endif;
endwhile;
sort($files);
foreach ($files as $file):
    echo '<div class="pattern">';
    echo '<div class="display">';
    include('patterns/'.$file);
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="source">';
    echo '<textarea rows="6" cols="30">';
    echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('patterns/'.$file));
    echo '</textarea>';
    echo '<p><a href="patterns/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: have you tried reading something on twig because this is all in the documentation here is the documentation for you https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/

Comment: You would need to compile an array of template parameters and pass that to the render method of the template engine.

Comment: ^ this - Same as you did in your `php` code, create an array of the files needed to be included. The only non-standard thing would be the `htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('patterns/'.$file));` line. This would require a custom twig function/filter

Comment: @DarkBee, are you saying I need to manually list out the files...like in a variable on the same page? I'm aiming to generate the page dynamically based on the content within the html files inside the folder. So there may be a button.html and header-one.html, but I don't want to manually place those file names on the page.

Answer (score 1):

*The following only works when using the `FilesystemLoader` - code is written for `twig 2.x` and is not tested*

---

register `twig` with `Filesystemloader`

```
<?php
    require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

    $loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader('/path/to/templates');
    $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);

    $twig->addFunction(new \Twig\TwigFunction('get_folder', function (\Twig\Environment $twig, $folder) {
            foreach($twig->getLoader()->getPaths() as $view_path) {
                if (is_dir($view_path.'/'.$folder)) {
                    $location = $view_path.'/'.$folder;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($location === null) return [];
            $it = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($location, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),\RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

            $templates = [];
            foreach($it as $path) $templates[] = str_replace($view_path.'/', '', $path);
            return $templates;
    }, ['needs_environment' => true, ]);
```

*Use new function inside `twig`*

```
{% for template in get_folder('patterns') %}
    {% include template %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think what you are looking for is a symphony twig introduction/tutorial:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html